# Админка для авторизованных пользователей сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net, cms

Делаем админку. Есть мастерпэйдж и страницы контента.

Для авторизовавшихся пользователей сверху должна появляться админка, содержимое которой должно **меняться в зависимости от того, какая страница открыта**. Как это реализовать?

Добрые люди говорят делать вложенную таблицу в верхней строке мастерпэйджа и делать её скрытой для неавторизованных. Я чего-то не уверен... **:)**

**Как** будут передаваться данные с открытой страницы контента в мастерпэйдж? (это ведь необходимо для реализации заявленных возможностей) **Не опасно ли** просто скрывать её для неавторизованных пользователей?

(VS 2010, .NET 4)

Comment: Прошу примеры использования компонентов Login и LoginView. 

В MSDN я нашёл только пошаговое руководство, которое ничего нового мне не дало - как проверять пароль/логин, где их хранить, как запоминать пользователя... не знаю... пока завёл таблицу USER в БД, там два поля - USERLOGIN и USERPASS - так можно?

Comment: По поводу контролов: данные контролы работают на основе Membership провайдера (дефолтная реализация желает лучшего, особенно профайл). Все настраивается практически без кодинга, базу надо генерировать, а не создавать свою с Юзерами (там уже есть). Контролы проверяют пароли и тд автоматически. Если хотите свои таблицы в БД надо переопределять соответственных провайдеров. Примеры приводить не буду - в инете их тьма. Гуглите по membership.

Comment: На офф сайте кстате тоже материалов завались, как и во многих книгах по АСП. А что у вас за ЦМС ?

Comment: Нет ЦМС. Делаю свой первый сайт. Сейчас делаю авторизацию для доступа к административной панели для контент-менеджмента (как сложно-то :)) - считай ЦМС и делаю :)

Спасибо вам за ответ.

Я, всё же, думаю, сделать с использованием TextBox и Button и таблицы в своей БД... как вы думаете, приемлем-ли такой вариант в плане безопасности ну и вообще, это не сильно убого? :) я вот тут код выкладывал http://hashcode.ru/questions/175834

Comment: Ну вообще конечно же приемлим, но чесно говоря убого, нет ролей и профайла. Как определить является ли юзер онлайн, как добавить юзеру роль? Как зарегаться? Будете опять таки делать руками, не смотря на то, что подобный функционал можно просто взять и заюзать. Велик вобщем создаете. Самый адекватный вариант - переопределить дефолтных провайдеров и настроить под себя. Надеюсь работа с БД происходит по средствам ОРМ? И еще - зачем создавать свою цмс, когда есть уже написанные? Ваша будет иметь преимущества? Проще опять таки поскилапить имеющую и на основе ее быстро делать проекты.

Comment: Хранить в сессии какие-то единицы сигнализируя, что юзер зашел на сайт, как минимум странно! Что если залогинится второй юзер? В случае, если на сайте будет всего один юзер и он же админ - порще такого юзера прописать в веб-конфиге.

Comment: "работа с БД происходит по средствам ОРМ"

ОРМ - что это?

в web.config определена connectionString и на каждой странице, использующей данные из БД, есть подключение к БД SqlConnection, во время которого и происходят манипуляции с данными БД.

Так правильно?

Comment: "В случае, если на сайте будет всего несколько юзеров - проще их прописать в веб-конфиге."

Как это сделать?

Какие трудности могут возникнуть при хранении в сессии данных об авторизации?

Comment: Сначала хотел использовать Joomla!, но потом интересней стало создать что-то своё. Это первый мой проект)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, если в `Web Forms` что-то скрывается, до клиента это вообще не доходит. Невидимый элемент просто не рендерится.

Comment: Спасибо. А вы лично бы стали использовать таблицу для этой цели? 

И как передать со страницы авторизации информацию о том, авторизовался пользователь или нет в мастерпэйдж? (Может, задать отдельный вопрос об этом?) 

Добрые люди говорят, нужно использовать межстраничную пересылку данных... 

Я чего-то не уверен... :) Такое ощущение, что для этого обычно используют cookies - записать данные об авторизации туда и из мастерпейджа проверять их при загрузке страницы. Только вот, что туда записывать, чтобы это было безопасно...

Answer (score 1):

В списке простых вариантов еще можно найти использование компонента *LoginView*, который можно легко настроить в зависимости от роли пришедшего юзера.

Comment: Спасибо. Я так понимаю, этот компонент специально для подобных целей и создан? Поищу информацию о нём... или может быть вы дадите более-менее общий пример?

Comment: Пока курил понял, что погорячился, назвав ваш подход приемлемым. Почитайте про аутентификацию в любой толковой книге по АСП.НЕТ, например Макдональд, Шпушта и КО